# Querying on multiple Hive stores using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-hive

I have a spark application which will successfully connect to hive and query on hive tables using spark engine.

To build this, I just added `hive-site.xml` to classpath of the application and spark will read the `hive-site.xml` to connect to its metastore. This method was suggested in spark's mailing list.

So far so good. Now I want to connect to two hive stores and I don't think adding another `hive-site.xml` to my classpath will be helpful. I referred quite a few articles and spark mailing lists but could not find anyone doing this.

Can someone suggest how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Docs referred:

- [Hive on Spark](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started)
- [Spak docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive)
- [HiveContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html)

Comment: Just an idea of a workaround: Hive data reside on HDFS anyway, you can create a DataFrame over a file or dir? I mean, `sc.wholeTextFiles('hdfs://host/usr/hive/warehouse/mytable')` will give you contents of Hive table. Sure, you will lose comfort of meta-data, but it might work out.

Comment: I've asked myself the same question, searched a lot, and read some of Spark's code - so far I'm almost convinced this is impossible, at least not in the same SparkContext :(

Comment: @karthik-manchala I tried to setup Spark-Hive and ran it HortonWorks Sandbox but i am getting some errors, can you help me out in this.

Comment: the code base is located at: https://github.com/ersanjayverma/spark-hive-solr-demo. I have posted a question at hortonworks community if want to have a look. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/65324/getting-exception-in-spark-hive-application.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is possible by making use of Spark SQL capability of connecting and reading data from remote databases using JDBC.

After an exhaustive R & D, I was successfully able to connect to two different hive environments using JDBC and load the hive tables as DataFrames into Spark for further processing.

**Environment details**

hadoop-2.6.0

apache-hive-2.0.0-bin

spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6

**Code Sample**  HiveMultiEnvironment.scala

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
object HiveMultiEnvironment {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JDBC").setMaster("local")
    var sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    var sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    // load hive table (or) sub-query from Environment 1

    val jdbcDF1 = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
      "url" -> "jdbc:hive2://<host1>:10000/<db>",
      "dbtable" -> "<db.tablename or subquery>",
      "driver" -> "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
      "user" -> "<username>",
      "password" -> "<password>"))
    jdbcDF1.foreach { println }
      
    // load hive table (or) sub-query from Environment 2

    val jdbcDF2 = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
      "url" -> "jdbc:hive2://<host2>:10000/<db>",
      "dbtable" -> "<db.tablename> or <subquery>",
      "driver" -> "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
      "user" -> "<username>",
      "password" -> "<password>"))
    jdbcDF2.foreach { println }
  }
  // todo: business logic
}
```

Other parameters can also be set during load using SqlContext such as setting partitionColumn. Details found under **'JDBC To Other Databases'** section in Spark reference doc:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html

Build path from Eclipse:

[image]

**What I Haven't Tried**

Use of HiveContext for Environment 1 and SqlContext for environment 2

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: This answer is definitely helpful. I have tried this before and problem with jdbc approach was.. I could not select specific columns from dataframe created

Comment: Strange, how it will work for analytical functions, since sqlContext wont support the analytical functions in hive. Can you explain me the above scenario with hivecontext??

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be possible in the current version of Spark. Reading the [HiveContext code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.scala) in the Spark Repo it appears that `hive.metastore.uris` is something that is configurable for many Metastores, but it appears to be used only for redundancy across the same metastore, not totally different metastores.

More information here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin

But you will probably have to aggregate the data somewhere in order to work on it in unison. Or you could create multiple Spark Contexts for each store.

You could try configuring the `hive.metastore.uris` for multiple different metastores, but it probably won't work. If you do decide to create multiple Spark contexts for each store than make sure you set `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` but this is generally discouraged and may lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Would you like to add some details? Maybe update to Spark 2.0.0?