# Spark thinks I'm reading DataFrame from a Parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Spark 2.x here. My code:

```
val query = "SELECT * FROM some_big_table WHERE something > 1"

val df : DataFrame = spark.read
  .option("url",
    s"""jdbc:postgresql://${redshiftInfo.hostnameAndPort}/${redshiftInfo.database}?currentSchema=${redshiftInfo.schema}"""
  )
  .option("user", redshiftInfo.username)
  .option("password", redshiftInfo.password)
  .option("dbtable", query)
  .load()
```

Produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:183)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

I'm not reading *anything* from a Parquet file, I'm reading from a Redshift (RDBMS) table. So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use generic `load` function you should include format as well:

```scala
// Query has to be subquery 
val query = "(SELECT * FROM some_big_table WHERE something > 1) as tmp"

...
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("dbtable", query)
  .load()
```

Otherwise Spark assumes that you use default format, which in presence of no specific configuration, is Parquet.

Also nothing forces you to use `dbtable`.

```scala
spark.read.jdbc(
  s"jdbc:postgresql://${hostnameAndPort}/${database}?currentSchema=${schema}",
  query, 
  props 
)
```

variant is also valid.

And of course with such simple query all of that it is not needed:

```scala
spark.read.jdbc(
  s"jdbc:postgresql://${hostnameAndPort}/${database}?currentSchema=${schema}",
  some_big_table, 
  props 
).where("something > 1")
```

will work the same way, and if you want to improve performance you should consider parallel queries

- [How to improve performance for slow Spark jobs using DataFrame and JDBC connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32188295/9613318)
- [Whats meaning of partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41085238/9613318)
- [Spark 2.1 Hangs while reading a huge datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45027091/9613318)
- [Partitioning in spark while reading from RDBMS via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43150694/9613318)

or even better, try [Redshift connector](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift).